# Get the Value of a byte with Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, byte

I'm not sure if the title makes any sense, but here is what I need.

This is my byte: ���������ˇ�����0F*E��ù�    �
I have already managed to get the values of this byte with this php snippet:

```
<?php
$var = "���������ˇ�����0F*E��ù�";

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($var); $i++)
{
   echo ord($var[$i])."<br/>";
}
?>
```

The result was:
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
2
2
0
255
0
0
0
0
0
2
48
70
1
42
69
0
0
1
157
0

But now I need to do the exact same thing without php, but in Java Script.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I don't think you're using the correct terminology: for one, JavaScript has no concept of a "byte", secondly a byte in most computers is an 8-bit value, what you've got looks like a string of text.

Comment: What do you have in javascript? In javascript strings are not byte arrays like they are in PHP. In javascript string is distinct from [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Typed_arrays/Uint8Array)/[Buffer](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you're wanting to get the numeric value of each character in a string in JavaScript, that can be done like so:

```
var someString = "blarg";

for(var i=0;i<someString.length;i++) {
    var char = someString.charCodeAt(i);

}
```

`String.charCodeAt(index)` returns the Unicode code-point value of the specified character in the string. It does not behave like PHP or C where it returns the numeric value of a fixed 8-bit encoding (i.e. ASCII). Assuming your string is a human-readable string (as opposed to raw binary data) then using `charCodeAt` is perfectly fine. If you're working with raw binary data then don't use a JavaScript string.

If your strings contain characters that have Unicode code-points below 128 then `charCodeAt` behaves the same as `ord` in PHP or C's `char` type, however the example you've provided contains non-ASCII characters, so Unicode's (sometimes complicated) rules will come into play.

See the documentation on `charCodeAt` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt

Comment: PHP "strings" represent arbitrary binary data, not just ASCII or even characters at all.

Comment: @Esailija That is what I meant :)

Comment: @Dai Thanks. I tried your solution, and got this: 65533
Here is the URL with your code:
http://ayroa.com/goproapp/test.html

I don't know what's the problem, but I need this to be my output: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 255 0 0 0 0 0 2 48 70 1 42 69 0 0 1 157 0

Answer (score 1):

The PHP String is computed as 8-bit (bytes 0..255) while JavaScript uses 16-bit unicode characters (0..65535). Depending on your string you may either split it into (16bit) char codes or into the bytes. If you know your String contains only 8-bit chars you may ignore the "hiByte" (see below) to get the same results as in PHP.

```
function toByteVersionA(s) {
    var len = s.length;
    // char codes
    var charCodes = new Array();
    for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        charCodes.push(s.charCodeAt(i).toString());
    }
    var charCodesString = charCodes.join(" ");
    return charCodesString;
}

function toByteVersionB(s) {
    var len = s.length;
    var bytes = new Array();
    for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        var charCode = s.charCodeAt(i);
        var loByte = charCode & 255;
        var hiByte = charCode >> 8;
        bytes.push(loByte.toString());
        bytes.push(hiByte.toString());
    }
   var bytesString = bytes.join(" ");
   return bytesString;
}

function toByteVersionC(s) {
   var len = s.length;
   var bytes = new Array();
   for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        var charCode = s.charCodeAt(i);
        var loByte = charCode & 255;
        bytes.push(loByte.toString());
   }
   var bytesString = bytes.join(" ");
   return bytesString;
}

var myString = "abc"; // whatever your String is
var myBytes = toByteVersionA(myString); // whatever version you want
```

Comment: thanks. I really don't have any knowledge about Java Script. Where do I have to enter the string "ˇ0F*Eù" in your Code?
And how can I get the output of the final number like in the php script?

Comment: I have modified the code so you can enter your String (variable myString) and get the converted bytes (variable myBytes).